# Converting DWG to GDB and maintaining style with Data Interoperability in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: style, file-geodatabase, arcgis-pro, dwg, data-interoperability

I am attempting to Convert a DWG to a geodatabase for online publishing and use in collector.

The conversion itself is fine, however I am also attempting to maintain style, i.e. annotation, colour, etc.

I have exposed autocad_color but obviously this is a numeric value, rather than RGB or something ArcGIS Pro can work with. I have also attempted to expose fme_color but that will not appear as an attribute. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In general *autocad_color* records the color of the linework in the original DWG file, and *fme_color* records that as the color in generic FME terms. Then when the data is written that *fme_color* is converted into a value usable for the output format.

However, the FME Readers and Writers manual suggests Geodatabase doesn't support recording the color of features. So this will not be an automatic process. What I think you'd need to do is record color as a "user attribute" and then use that in some sort of process inside ArcGIS *(Apologies, you probably knew this, but I like to be thorough)*

It should be fairly straightforward to turn an FME color into RGB. There's a ColorConverter transformer on the FME Hub, but if the Data Interoperability extension doesn't allow that, then it's just a case of splitting the value into three parts (AttributeSplitter) and multiplying each by 255 (ExpressionEvaluator or AttributeManager).

Of course you mention that *fme_color* will not appear as an attribute. Are you using the feature type parameters (Format Attributes tab) or the AttributeExposer transformer? Does it just not appear in the list in the Format Attributes tab? Or can you check it and then there is no attribute? I'm 99.9% sure that fme_color is there, even if you can't see it, so copying it with an AttributeManager will work, even if there is a red flag on the transformer.